# phpMyAdmin and MySQL 8.0 gives error

Tags: mysql, gui, syntax, phpmyadmin

**H!@all**

I am new to databases and this is the first time I have installed a MySQL-Server.

When I run commands in phpMyAdmin I keep getting error messages. I have noticed that the syntax in MySQL 8.0 has changed. As I understand it, phpMyAdmin still runs with the old syntaxes.

What options do I have to manage MySQL 8.0 via a graphical user interface?

[image: phpMyAdmin error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are being generated by the Mysql server itself, not by phpMyAdmin, which just connects then passes your commands through and displays the results.

Its the command itself that is incorrect.

Note that different linux distributions might have replaced Mysql with something like Mariadb

To be sure you're using the correct commands for the sql server you're running, verify it with

> SELECT version();